# Not able to access classes in javamail in OSGi

Tags: osgi

I have an OSGi bundle and I'm using java mail api in it to add mail functionality.

The problem I'm facing is, the bundle class loader is not adding the entries for mail-1.4.jar and activation.jar in classpath variable which it creates while loading the local or global classes.

I've added the mail-1.4.jar and activation.jar in the bundle classpath in manifest and these jar are simple jars(not the OSGi bundles). And these are in lib directory in my bundle.
Now while loading javax.mail.Address class ClassNotFoundException is thrown.
And this is when I'm running my application using command line.

It works completely fine when I run it in Eclipse.
I'm using equinox as my container.
Any suggestions?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Workexp
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.gslab.workexp
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.gslab.workexp.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: GSLAB
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar,
 lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,
 lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar,
 lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar,
 lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar,
 lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/iText-2.1.7.jar,
 lib/jasperreports-4.6.0.jar,
 lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar,
 lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar,
 lib/mail-1.4.jar,
 lib/activation.jar
```

Comment: You should post your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for your bundle. Normally dependent JARs that are not bundles in their own right must be placed in the Bundle-ClassPath entry of the MANIFEST.MF. Also, are you sure it's just a CNFE and not a NoClassDefFoundError? Post the entire stack trace.

Comment: yes its CNFE for sure. Sorry can not post the stack trace as its not shown on console. I did remote debugging using eclipse and there I saw while calling delegate.findclass for javax.mail.Address it throwed CNFE.

Comment: Another thing to try is to enable debugging such that Equinox shows which classes are being loaded and from where. Check out http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html to set up logging.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I used JDWP to remotely debug the application and did see that while loading javax.mail.Address class it throwed CNFE and the stacktrace value was null.

Comment: Yes, but you'll see *why* it threw a CNFE. You'll see explicitly which bundle attempted to load the class. Remember that OSGi classloading is more complex in the sense of 'wiring' between bundles etc.

Comment: Another thing: I assume that MANIFEST.MF is the design time version and not the runtime version. The Bundle-Classpath is invalid for runtime because of those newlines.

Comment: I've seen the classpath variable entries while debugging. It had all the jars mentioned in the bundle-classpath. Still it showed CNFE

Comment: What do you mean by 'classpath variable entries'? It has nothing to do with the VM's classpath. These JARs should be loaded by the OSGi classloader. 'classpath' is a way of specifying JARs/class roots via the command line. Actually, if these JARs are ALSO on the classpath, that might be a cause of your problem.

Comment: No I've not added jars on command line cp

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the bundle classpath is unusual. You should use Import-Package (best practice) or Require-Bundle for dependencies. Bundle classpath is saying all those jars are packaged inside a lib folder inside your bundle archive. I suspect this isn't the case, and even if it was, you'd be totally bypassing all the modularity Eclipse gives you.

Try adding the 'javax.mail' package to your Import-Package header. For an explanation of why this isn't needed in Eclipse, see i/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix%3F.

Comment: I agree about the best practice. But the mail.jar is placed inside the lib folder inside my bundle archive. There must not be CNFE.

Comment: And for the issue which you mentioned while launching OSGi i use java -Dosgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true.

Comment: Are you specifying both the bootdelegation property *and* packaging the jar inside your bundle? You'll then potentially have two copies of the javax.mail packages visible to your bundle, which is a good recipe for weird classpath problems.

Comment: I didnt get it. How are there two copies?.. rt.jar does not have javax.mail.

Comment: You said about about the JAR being on the 'classpath'. That would make two copies: one via the classpath, one via OSGi Bundle-Classpath. Bundle-Classpath and 'classpath' are VERY different things.

Comment: No no.. I'm not providing jar via -cp in command line.. Its only in the bundle archieve.. Sorry if my comments seemed that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included your lib folder inside the bin.includes (Build Tab in the Manifest editor) or they won't get exported in the final jar.
This is a very annoying 'bug' that it works in eclipse (because the files are accessible in the file system) but the builder will ignore not included files.